# iOS Copy Files to external device

Tags: file-manager, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am developing an iOS App that will write files to an external device. I have installed and used UIDocumentPicker with the following code:
let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forExporting: usbSendungURL)
documentPickerController.delegate = self
self.present(documentPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
Which successfully copied to my device.
However as these files can be somewhat large I decided that I needed to install a UIProgressView. Unfortunately DocumentPicker doesn’t doesn’t have this function so I changed my code as follows:
let documentPickerController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.folder])
documentPickerController.delegate = self
self.present(documentPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
That enabled me to pick up the selected folder in the delegate:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    documentPickerUrls = urls
    moveFilesToUSB(urls: urls)
}
```

I then append the filenames as appropriate and used FileManager moveItem function:
try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: usbSendungURL[0], to: url1!)
Which enabled me to install the necessary timer functions for the progress updates.
Unfortunately FileManager appears not to able to write to an external device as I am receiving an error message that states that the I don’t have authorisation to write to the device although DocumentPicker does.
Is there a way around this issue.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The URLs returned by `UIDocumentPickerViewController` are *security-scoped* and access to the directory requires the use of `url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` and `url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()`. This is explained clearly in [Providing Access To Directories](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories?language=objc).

Comment: Thanks, the explanation has helped. I now have access to an external device to which I can now write files. However it appears that I only have access to the main directory on the device. If I select a sub folder I am told that I do not have authority to access the main folder. I have tried startAccessSecurity for each intermediate directory without success. I am still searching through the various websites that cover this function but to date have found nothing. However if you know of a way to access sub directories I would be keen to know. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have followed the pattern described in that article, and am able to recursively traverse directories and read files in each. Whether the directory is  in iCloud Drive, SMB Share or "On My iPad". I have built a simple free app that demonstrates this [Samurai Search](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1576636770) You could use it to test your situation.

Comment: I can read files in each directory, the issue I have is that I am only able to write files to the main directory. If I try writing to a sub directory I am told that I have no authority to write to the main directory although I have security scoped the sub directory.

Comment: I admit the security scoped URLS are not always obvious. Sometimes you need them, sometimes you don't. If you have requested scoped access to the directory AND the url you want to write to - I'm not sure what else you can be do. Perhaps post a very explicit failing example here and to the Apple Developer forum?